# How to remove class to row-id?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove class only selected row because in a laravel `foreach loop` I have multiple rows like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="remove-d-none">Use</a>
    <div class="d-none manue">
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <a class="remove-d-none">Use</a>
    <div class="d-none manue">
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I wanted it so that if the user clicks on first row only, its class should be removed so I tried this:

```
$('.remove-d-none').on('click', function(){
    $('.menu').removeClass('d-none');
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Does somebody know how to help?

Comment: Opps your both menu spelling is different ! even from which d-none you want to remove !

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.d-none').removeClass('d-done')`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: class manue should be menu  in  <div class="d-none manue">, its a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.remove-d-none').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".manue").removeClass("d-none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="remove-d-none">Use</a>
      <div class="d-none manue">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="remove-d-none">Use</a>
      <div class="d-none manue">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```